# KdV equation - wavebreaking and Galerkin method

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

I want to show how a wave given by the initial condition: 
$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
u(x, 0) = \left\{\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{\quad}l@{}}
    1 - x^2 & \text{for $\left| x \right| \le 1$}\\
    0 & \text{for $\left| x \right| > 1$}\\
  \end{array}\right.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
$$
being the solution of 
$$
u_{t} + uu_{x} = 0
$$
behaves in time.
I use the Galerkin method.

```
kdVmod[tmax_, Δt_, fmin_, fmax_] := Module[{k, ODEs},

  k[n_] = n Pi/L;

  ODEs = Table[
               D[c[n][t], t] + Sum[ I k[nb]  c[nb][t] c[n - nb][t], {nb, -M, M}] == 0,
               {n, 0, M}];

  vars = Table[c[n][t], {n, 0, M}];

  sol = NDSolve[Join[ODEs, ics], vars, {t, 0, tmax}, 
                MaxSteps -> 10000, 
                Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"} ];

  f[x_, t_] = Sum[c[n][t] Exp[I k[n] x], {n, -M, M}];
  f[x_, t_] = f[x, t] /. sol[[1]];

  Table[Print[
    Plot[f[x, t], {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> {{-L, L}, {fmin, fmax}}, 
        PlotLabel -> "t = " <> ToString[t]]], {t, 0, tmax, Δt}];]
```

Is it possible to somehow parametrically solve the equation to obtain good results for $t > 0.5$ (for this condition and for $x > 1$ there are "two values" and that is the problem)...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Your code cannot be run as given.  It is, for instance, missing  definitions for `M`, `L`, and `ics`.  Typical values of the arguments used to call `kdVmod` also are needed.

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of a functioning code in the Question, I used the straightforward

```
L = 1.5;
s = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t] D[u[x, t], x] == 0, 
   u[L, t] == u[-L, t], u[x, 0] == Max[1 - x^2, 0]}, 
   u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, 1}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001];
Plot3D[s[x, t], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Despite a warning message about error estimates, the answer seems insensitive to `MaxStepSize`, suggesting that it is correct.

[image]

The Question also states that two solutions exist for `t > 1/2` and asked how to compute both.  If the solution does indeed bifurcate at that point, it is unlikely that the second solution can be computed numerically, because one of the two solutions in such bifurcations typically is unstable.